# Resizing window with text scaling

Tags: window, scaling, zooming

I often have multiple windows in `emacs`.  I would like to have a function that modifies the width of a window to a certain value, then scales the text such that the longest line in the buffer fits the window leaving a small margin at the end (e.g. of two or three characters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commands `text-scale-decrease`, `text-scale-increase`, and
`text-scale-adjust` (bound to `C-x C--`, `C-x C-+`, `C-x C-=`, and
`C-x C-0`) let you resize the text in the current buffer by
changing its scale factor.  When you shrink or enlarge the
apparent text size this way, however, the window takes no notice
of it.  In particular, although shrinking text can result in extra
horizontal space at the right, window commands do not see this
space as extra.

If you use library [**`face-remap+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/face-remap%2b.el) then you can do what you want, or at least something similar, which you can modify.

User option `text-scale-resize-window` lets you
automatically resize the selected window (horizontally,
vertically, or both) when text is resized, so that the way the
window fits the buffer text remains relatively constant.
Shrinking the text in one window shrinks that window, giving more
space to adjacent windows.

If you also use library [`fit-frame.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/fit-frame.el), then one-window frames
also respond to text resizing by scaling.  If not, then the
text-scale commands have no effect on frame size for one-window
frames. (See also [Shrink-Wrapping Frames](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Shrink-Wrapping_Frames).)

Comment: Sometimes, when I scale down, I see that the next line continuation marker gets displayed in the fringe.

Comment: I also see that you have redefined the scaling commands.  I am critical of such design, because the normal functionality has its use.

Comment: The vanilla behavior is available with option `text-scale-resize-window` = `nil`.

Comment: Good. Have found a slight problem because `(require 'face-remap+)` seems to enable the resize feature.  But most functionality, does not take effect simply by requiring a feature.

Comment: Could you fix the situation where the resizing ends up continuing on next line, even when at first there is some space between the longest line and the window edge?

Comment: Using the library is optional. Setting the option to nil, as I said, gives you vanilla behavior.

Comment: Have you noticed the line continuation effect?